# regex only start with value1 without value1\nvalue2

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

New in regex,trying catch files on server where string start with only value1 but if we have in file value1 and next string value2 we don't add it  in output

`keyword = re.findall(r'^process.args=spring.*?xml(?!process.script=true)', line,re.S)`

Any advices please?

need output like this :

````
xxxx xxx xxx xxx
process.args=spring.xxxx.xml
process.script=true
xxxx xxx xxx xxx\n```

output after regex : None

and 

```xx xx xxx xxx xxx
xxxx xxx xxx xxx
process.args=spring.xxxx.xml
xxxx xxx xxx xxx```

output after regex : process.args=spring.xxxx.xml
````

Comment: Can you post examples of inputs and what should match and what should not?

Comment: Don't forget to escape `.` in the regexp if you intend it to be literal.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `^process\.args=spring.*?xml(?!\r?\nprocess\.script=true)`

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica added output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern you use the negative lookahead `xml(?!process` right after `xml`. But as it is at the end of the string, you could prepend matching a newline before `\r?\nprocess`

Note that if `.xml` is at the end of the string, you don't have to make the dot non greedy and that you have to escape the dot to match it literally.

You could also add a word boundary after true to make sure it is not part of a longer word.

```
^process\.args=spring.*\.xml(?!\r?\nprocess\.script=true\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pkiTbf/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aeoDzv)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^process\.args=spring.*\.xml(?!\r?\nprocess\.script=true\b)"

line = ("xxxx xxx xxx xxx\n"
    "process.args=spring.xxxx.xml\n"
    "process.script=true\n"
    "xxxx xxx xxx xxx\n\n\n"
    "xx xx xxx xxx xxx\n"
    "xxxx xxx xxx xxx\n"
    "process.args=spring.xxxx.xml\n"
    "xxxx xxx xxx xxx")

res = re.findall(regex, line, re.MULTILINE)
print(res)
```

Output

```
['process.args=spring.xxxx.xml']
```

Comment: @IgorShilov You could use re.findall if you want. See this demo https://ideone.com/aeoDzv

Comment: @IgorShilov Glad it works. If the answer helped solving the problem, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Have a question. if value2 do not start  after value1 but we have value 2 in file. What we gonna do in this case?

Comment: If it is on the next line but not at the start, you could add `.*` like `(?!\r?\n.*process` If it can be anywhere, you could make the dot match a newline using `re.S` along with the `.*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204604/discussion-between-igor-shilov-and-the-fourth-bird).